# Closure Compiler - List all the externs used?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I am new to Closure Compiler and when I compile a library I have to work with, a line like this intrigues me:

```
   [jscomp] Compiling 197 file(s) with 41 extern(s)
```

I'd say some common Web variables like `document` and `window` are in, but do I have a way to see this list? `java -jar compiler.jar --help` didn't give me a hint to such an option. That option should output a list like the following:

- document (from gecko_dom.js)
- window (from gecko_dom.js)
- ...

with a total of exactly 41 items. The "(from..." is optional but of course good to have.

Comment: The 41 externs are 41 files used as externs in the compilation - not 41 types. There are hundreds of types. There is no option in the compiler to list the extern types.

Answer (score 0):

By default, closure-compiler uses all of the externs in this folder: https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#git%2Fexterns

They are packaged as part of the compiler jar.

Additional externs are available at https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#git%2Fcontrib%2Fexterns but must be manually included with the `--externs` flag.

Comment: Perhaps the link should now be to https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/externs/browser

Answer (score 0):

The definitive list of default externs is listed in the command-line runner source:

https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner.java#868

Comment: Yes, that's a useful list, but of course I'd rather not manually check in each file and see waht these 41 externs are.

Comment: @kennyluck I'm really not sure what you are asking then. The default externs are divided into separate files because they are too big to be manageable in a single file.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth I want Closure list those 41 externs. I have change my question to be more explicit. I hope that's clear now. And of course you are welcome to change the question further as I am not really sure why my question would be interpreted into a request for all **possible** externs.